# How to iterate through a datadump and paste unique values into two separate tables [VBA]

Tags: excel, vba, loops, foreach

I currently have two spreadsheets: one that pulls data from a SQL Server and is a data dump and one that needs to have those values populated into them. For the sake of simplicity, I've compiled a mini prototype to use for the purpose of my question. Things to note, the data dump sheet will have a varying amount of rows, however the columns will be static which should hopefully make for easy mapping. What I need my macro to be able to accomplish is to

1. Check if an ID value matches the one directly below it, if so
2. Check if the Spouse_Indicator field has an "N" or "Y" value
3. If the indicator is an "N" value then I need the corresponding rows from the employer and title fields to be populated into the student table
4. If the indicator is a "Y" value then I need the corresponding rows from the employer and title fields to be populated into the spouse table
5. If there is a sequence where the ID does not match the one directly below it, the data automatically gets populated into the student table

The problem that I am having with the way that my macro is set up is that only the most recent ID with a "N" indicator is getting populated into every cell of the student table whereas I need only unique values to be populated until the last ID has been read. The image attached shows a small sample size of the data, the first table shows what my macro is producing while the last table shows my target. I am also including my code to show what I've gotten so far. Let me know if I need to clarify anything, thanks a bunch.

[image]

```
Sub test2()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim id As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim student_employer As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set id = ws.Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
Set student_employer = ws.Range("G3:G8")

For Each cell In id
    If cell.Value = cell.Offset(1, 0).Value And cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "N" Then
        cell.Offset(0, 2).Copy student_employer.Cells
    End If
Next

MsgBox ("DONE")

End Sub
```

I've edited my code and it is somewhat capturing what I am trying to accomplish, however I need the values to be pasted into the next empty cell, while mine currently skips the amount of cells depending on when the next copy-paste takes place.

```
Sub test2()

Dim id As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim emp As Range
Set emp = Range("G3:G8")

id = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For x = 2 To id
If Cells(x, 1).Value = Cells(x, 1).Offset(1, 0) Then
    Cells(x, 1).Offset(0, 2).Copy Cells(x, 6).Offset(1, 0)
End If

Next x

MsgBox ("DONE")

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You should have counters for student and spouse lists so you will know which row the next record should go. Also, `cell.offset(0,2)` would just copy the employer column. `cell.copy` for id and `cell.offset(0,2).resize(1,2).copy` for employer-title columns should get you going.

Comment: Hi @Gokhan, I've never tried using counters so if you have time to spare, would you mind showing what you mean? Also, the suggestion you provided kind of works, however the data is not being pasted into the next empty cell of the table, there are spaces inbetween, so is there a way to force paste into the next empty cell? Thanks

Comment: Just as an example, `Dim rowStudent as Long, rowSpouse as Long`. `rowStudent = 3`. `rowSpouse = 9`. Then when you copy a new student, use rowStudent as row number, and `rowStudent = rowStudent + 1` after the copy. rowSpouse just the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Copy Unique Rows

- Adjust the values in the constants section. If you feel like it, use the out-commented constants and `sCols` to get rid of the 'magic' numbers (`1, 2, 3, 4`).
- For the sake of simplicity, it is assumed that the source data starts in cell `A1` (`CurrentRegion`).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test1()
    
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    'Const sCritCol As Long = 2
    'Const sColsList As String = "1,3,4"
    'Const scCount As Long = 4
    Const sCrit1 As String = "N"
    Const sCrit2 As String = "Y"
    
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dFirst As String = "F1"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    If srg.Columns.Count <> 4 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    If srCount = 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = srg.Value
    
    'Dim sCols() As String: sCols = Split(sColsList, ",")
    
    Dim dict1 As Object: Set dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict1.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    Dim dict2 As Object: Set dict2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict2.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim cDat As Variant: ReDim cDat(1 To 3)
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim sCrit As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 2 To srCount
        sCrit = sData(r, 2)
        Select Case UCase(CStr(sCrit))
        Case sCrit1
            Key = sData(r, 1)
            If Not dict1.Exists(Key) Then
                cDat(1) = sData(r, 1)
                cDat(2) = sData(r, 3)
                cDat(3) = sData(r, 4)
                dict1(Key) = cDat
            End If
        Case sCrit2
            Key = sData(r, 1)
            If Not dict2.Exists(Key) Then
                cDat(1) = sData(r, 1)
                cDat(2) = sData(r, 3)
                cDat(3) = sData(r, 4)
                dict2(Key) = cDat
            End If
        End Select
    Next r
    
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = dict1.Count + dict2.Count + 4
    
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To 3)
    
    r = 1
    dData(r, 1) = "student"
    r = r + 1
    dData(r, 1) = sData(1, 1)
    dData(r, 2) = sData(1, 3)
    dData(r, 3) = sData(1, 4)
    
    Dim n As Long
    If dict1.Count > 0 Then
        For Each Key In dict1.Keys
            r = r + 1
            For n = 1 To 3
                dData(r, n) = dict1(Key)(n)
            Next n
        Next Key
    End If
    
    r = r + 1
    dData(r, 1) = "spouse"
    r = r + 1
    dData(r, 1) = sData(1, 1)
    dData(r, 2) = sData(1, 3)
    dData(r, 3) = sData(1, 4)
    
    If dict2.Count > 0 Then
        For Each Key In dict2.Keys
            r = r + 1
            For n = 1 To 3
                dData(r, n) = dict2(Key)(n)
            Next n
        Next Key
    End If
            
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            
    ' Write.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range(dFirst).Resize(r, 3)
    drg.Clear ' because of merged cells
    drg.Value = dData
    
    ' Clear below.
    Dim crg As Range
    Set crg = drg.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - drg.Row - r + 1).Offset(r)
    crg.Clear

    ' Format 'student'
    With drg.Rows(1)
        .Cells(1).Font.Bold = True
        .MergeCells = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .BorderAround xlContinuous, xlThick
    End With
    
    ' Format 'spouse'.
    With drg.Rows(dict1.Count + 3)
        .Cells(1).Font.Bold = True
        .MergeCells = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .BorderAround xlContinuous, xlThick
    End With
    
    ' Format all.
    drg.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox ("DONE")

End Sub
```